# How to implement click event on toolbar icon?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, onclicklistener, toolbar, onitemclicklistener

I want to switch activity on click of toolbar icon.

[image]

my code :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mytoolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

and handled on click like this but its not working:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/rel_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.project.www.simpleproject.activity.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/AppToolbar">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Is it possible and if yes, then let me know thankyou

Comment: try the solution  before asking

Comment: I tried but its not working.

Comment: what's not working

Comment: Try add `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`

Comment: still not working..

Comment: And also `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: @MayurKharche check the answer man

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also have this without using `Toolbar`.

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
 actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

Then

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved, Thank you

Comment: yes, i replace icon with HomeAsUpIndicator and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this along with your `getSupportActionBar`:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```